# IBM Rational Rhapsody Compilation error

Tags: visual-c++

I created a small model in rhapsody and i try to build it,then i am getting the following error
Building ------------  DefaultComponent.exe   ------------
Executing: ""C:\ProgramData\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.2\Share"\etc\msvcmake.bat DefaultComponent.mak build x86 VC11 "
The system cannot find the path specified.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0xff'
Stop.
Build Done

Please tell me what i should do to solve it,please please give reply if anyone knows.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your compiler is not installed where Rhapsody expects it.
in /Share/etc you will find the msmake.bat file. remove the REM in the first line then yogurt more information on what goes wrong.
Also you can edit the file to call the right compiler.
If you don't have Visual Studio, you can try cygwin as well

W.